# callout boxes not aligning with aligned environment content

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I've been able to create the `split rectangle` successfully.  I've been able to work with `\tikzmark` and `callout` boxes.  But now that I'm combining the two, something is going seriously wrong.

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset
  {
    set frame design/.style={rounded corners=15, 
                             line width=1.4pt, 
                             inner sep=2ex,
                             color=frame_color,
                             text=title_text_color,
                            },
    rectangle split in two/.style={rectangle split, 
                                   rectangle split parts=2, 
                                  },
  }

\colorlet{title_text_color}{blue}
\colorlet{title_bg_color}{yellow!10}
\colorlet{content_text_color}{blue}
\colorlet{content_bg_color}{red!20}
\colorlet{frame_color}{purple}

\newenvironment{myframed}[1]
  {\def\myframedtitle{#1}%%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw let \p1=($(\linewidth,0)-(1cm,0)$), 
               \p2=(0,0.5\baselineskip)
               in node [ 
                         draw, 
                         anchor=north,
                         set frame design,
                         rectangle split in two,
                         rectangle split part fill={title_bg_color,
                                                    content_bg_color},
                         rectangle split empty part height=\y2
                       ] (this_split_frame) at (0,0) 
               \bgroup 
                \nodepart{second} 
                \begin{minipage}{\x1}
                  \begin{minipage}{0.60\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
                  \color{title_text_color}
  }
  {               \end{minipage}
                \end{minipage}
             \egroup;
     \node [
            set frame design,
            anchor=north west,
            text=title_text_color
           ] at (this_split_frame.north west) { \bf\large \myframedtitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

%% setting `inner sep` and `outer sep` helps a little but doesn't correct things
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};}
%%  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]\node (#1) {};}

\newcommand\mynote[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rectangle callout, 
        draw=blue,
        fill=blue!10,
        text width=4cm,
        align=center,
        #1] at #2 {#3};
  \end{tikzpicture}%'
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{myframed}{Case: same denominator}
  Here is some text \tikzmark{a}\par
  Here's some more text \tikzmark{b}
%%  \begin{align*}
%%    \frac{3}{5} + \frac{4}{5} 
%%    & = \tikzmark{a} \frac{3+4}{5}  \\[2ex] %% 
%%    & = \tikzmark{b} \frac{7}{5}   
%%  \end{align*}
\end{myframed}

\mynote[callout relative pointer={(-1,0)}]
       {(a)}
       {Keep the denominator}

\mynote[callout relative pointer={(-1,0)}]
       {(b)}
       {Combine numerators}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

It seems to me that part of the problem is that `\tikzmark` is inheriting the settings from `\tikzset`  It would be nice to know how to turn these off contextually.

I can improve things a bit by redefining `\tikzmark` as follows:

```
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,
        overlay,anchor=center,
        draw=none,
        rectangle split parts=1,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        rounded corners=0]\node (#1) {};}
```

But still the `callout` boxes are not positioned correctly and the node defined by `\tikzmark` is still visible.  As can be seen by using

```
\mynote[callout relative pointer={(-1,0)}]
       {([xshift=0in]a.east)}
       {Keep the denominator}

\mynote[callout relative pointer={(-1,0)}]
       {([yshift=-1in]b)}
       {Combine numerators}
```

[image]

**FURTHER UPDATE**

Things can be somewhat better improved by chaning the definition of `\tikzmark` to

```
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,
        overlay,
        ]\coordinate (#1) at (0,0) ;
  }
```

By using the following command, you can see that the coordinates are placed where expected:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw (a) -- (b) ;
```

I've moved the `callout` boxes by using `yshift`s to help see where this line would be drawn:

[image]

So the question remains of why the `callout` box is not pointing to the correct coordinate.

**SOLUTION**

The problem is that I'm not referring to the reference point correctly.  If instead I write

```
\mynote[callout absolute pointer={($(a)+(1.25cm,0)$)}]
       {([xshift=2in]a)}
       {Keep the denominator}

\mynote[callout absolute pointer={($(b)+(1.25cm,0)$)}]
       {([xshift=2in]b)}
       {Combine numerators}
```

then I get the desired result:

[image]

Comment: what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm expecting the boxes to be placed to the right of the text for which line the node has been defined.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Also, I don't understand how to get ride of the weird split boxes popping up.  I mean, obviously `\tikzmark` is inheriting the `rectangle split`, but I don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: So, if I understand, "Keep the denominator" should be to the right of and on the same vertical level as "Here is some text"?  Likewise, "Combine numerators" to the right of "Here is some more text"??

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes.  Initially, I thought the problem was because I was using the `align` environment.  I suppose I should have posted with the `align` content uncommented.  Basically, I wanted `callout` boxes to appear to the right of each line of text in the `align` environment.

Comment: Can you not put the solution in the question but instead but it into a self answer (which you can accept)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry.  :(  I was hoping someone else might have a better solution.  But, I'll do as you request.

Comment: @A.Ellett well in that case you can answer but not accept it and add a comment asking for better answers:-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with what I was doing.  Here's a solution I came up with, but I'm very open to someone else coming along and doing a nicer job.

The first was that I should have defined the `\tikzmark` in terms of a `coordinate`, which has zero dimension, rather than a `node`, which has dimensions and will inherit the attributes of the `node` its nested within.

```
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,
        overlay,
        ]\coordinate (#1) at (0,0) ;
  }
```

The second problem with the pointers was with how I was referencing them  I'm still a bit murky on this one, but the following code gets the `callout` boxes positioned better.  I should have been using the key `callout absolute pointer` and using a node modifier to get the callout boxes placed appropriately:

```
\mynote[callout absolute pointer={($(a)+(1.25cm,0)$)},anchor=west]
       {([xshift=0.75in]a)}
       {Keep the common denominator and write a new fraction with this common denominator.}
```

To make things work a bit better, I loaded the `varwidth` package.  Here's the final document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset
  {
    set frame design/.style={rounded corners=15, 
                             line width=1.4pt, 
                             inner sep=2ex,
                             color=frame_color,
                             text=title_text_color,
                            },
    rectangle split in two/.style={rectangle split, 
                                   rectangle split parts=2, 
                                  },
  }

\colorlet{title_text_color}{blue}
\colorlet{title_bg_color}{yellow!10}
\colorlet{content_text_color}{blue}
\colorlet{content_bg_color}{red!20}
\colorlet{frame_color}{purple}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{myframed}[1]
  {\def\myframedtitle{#1}%%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw let \p1=($(\textwidth,0)-2*(2ex,0)-2*(1.4pt,0)$), 
               \p2=(0,0.5\baselineskip)
               in node [ 
                         draw, 
                         anchor=north,
                         set frame design,
                         rectangle split in two,
                         rectangle split part fill={title_bg_color,
                                                    content_bg_color},
                         rectangle split empty part height=\y2
                       ] (this_split_frame) at (0,0) 
               \bgroup 
                \nodepart{second} 
                \begin{minipage}{\x1}
                  \begin{minipage}{0.50\linewidth}\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
                  \color{title_text_color}
  }
  {               \end{minipage}
                \end{minipage}
             \egroup;
     \node [
            set frame design,
            anchor=north west,
            text=title_text_color
           ] at (this_split_frame.north west) { \bf\large \myframedtitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,
        overlay,
        ]\coordinate (#1) at (0,0.75ex) ;
  }


\newlength{\mynotewidth}
\setlength{\mynotewidth}{5cm}
\newcommand\mynote[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rectangle callout, 
        fill=blue!10,
        draw=blue,
        #1] at #2 {\begin{varwidth}{\mynotewidth}{#3}\end{varwidth}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%'
  }

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{myframed}{Case: same denominator}
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{3}{5} + \frac{4}{5} 
    & = \tikzmark{a} \frac{3+4}{5}  \\[2ex] 
    & = \tikzmark{b} \frac{7}{5}   
  \end{align*}
\end{myframed}

\mynote[callout absolute pointer={($(a)+(1.25cm,0)$)},anchor=west]
       {([xshift=0.75in]a)}
       {Keep the common denominator and write a new fraction with this common denominator.}

\mynote[callout absolute pointer={($(b)+(1.25cm,0)$)},anchor=west]
       {([xshift=0.75in]b)}
       {Combine the numerators}

\end{document}
```

[image]